# What are the best macro-areas for an Editing Tool Dashboard?

Tags: web-app, information-architecture, dashboard

I am a designer, working on an editing tool.
The tool will be an online platform used by a team of instructional designers to create presentations. You have an editor where you create the presentations and a dashboard where these are saved.

The designers need to:
Quickly access what they are working on.
Easily group similar presentations.
Invite colleagues to work and review.

I wonder what are the clearest, most simple macro-areas to find on the dashboard to organize the files created. Any good examples?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Please expand on your use case. Who is this tool for? What are they using it for? What has your research revealed regarding how they use such tools?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, I just updated the Question. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the extra details. What do you mean by ‘macro-areas’?

Comment: I mean how to differentiate between All Files, ones I created and ones that have been shared with me.
Like Google Drive has: My Files, Shared Drives and Shared with me.
I like how a platform called Typeform forces you to create a "Workspace" inside which you can save files and you can invite people to. That keep the dashboard much simpler in that you don't have single files shared but just a list of "Workspaces"

Answer (score 0):

The answer would highly depend on how the team of instructional designers create the presentation, the workflow they use, who is involved, etc.

For example, if we are talking about one instructor managing one or two classes, a simple list of presentations which can be filtered by mine vs shared by others would suffice.

However, if for example, an instructor teaches multiples classes and wants to organize the presentations by classes, then a grouping/folder organization can be introduced in addition to simply filtering.

As per your description, it seems you need both filtering and grouping features as well as sharing on the file and folder level. As for sorting, include the usual options found in GDrive, such as Date Modified (to quickly access the latest presentation and continue working), alphabetical, etc.

In regards to Typeform, their “Workspace” is simply a group of surveys. Much like a folder is usually a group of files. A surveyor might have multiple projects (Workspaces) running in parallel with multiple surveys for each. Such a setup is applicable to a wide ranger of use cases including yours.

I would recommend to start with the simple setup described above and gather some feedback form your users. Or if you can, improve the tool overtime with this feedback. A simple and familiar organization structure has the benefits of familiarity, speed, etc. Overdoing it may result in unintended usability blockers (learning curve) and unneeded development issues.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, thanks so much, clear and spot on your feedback.
If I may ask do you have any good examples? thanks again.

Comment: I think any of the bigger platforms will give you a good start. GDrive, Google Slides, Dropbox, Box. Something a bit different would be https://app.boords.com/

Comment: Also checkout Notion. It has workspace + team options.